# values not adding to db from simplepie

Tags: php, simplepie

I am trying to fetch feeds using Simplepie, but when using some sources (like [this](http://munchies.vice.com/en_us/rss) and [this](https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss)) values are not inserting to the database.

Can someone help solve the issue?

```
$feedurls = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
  array_push($feedurls, $row['source_name']);
}

// var_dump($feedurls);

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feedurls);


$feed->init();
$feed->set_cache_location('/var/www/simplepie/library/cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(600);
$feed->handle_content_type();

    // Begin feed output

    $title;
    $description;
    $url;
    $thumbnail;
    $source;

        foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item){
            $title=$item->get_title();
        $description=$item->get_description();
       echo $item->get_description();
        echo $item->get_link();
        $url=$item->get_link();
         echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

        $enclosure= $item->get_enclosure();
         echo $enclosure->get_thumbnail();
          echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
         $thumbnail=$enclosure->get_thumbnail();


        $source = $item->get_feed()->subscribe_url() ;


enter code here
$insert = "INSERT INTO rss_feed(Heading,Description,News_URL,Image_URL,source_link)VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$url',' $thumbnail','$source')";
```

Comment: Welcome. What should `$title;` or `$description;` do? How is this question related to `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: $description=$item->get_description();
 $title=$item->get_title();
These are the title and description of rss news.
I am doing this in XAMPP so I added phpmyadmin in tags

Comment: The phpMyAdmin application is an interface for administrators to manage a MySQL/MariaDB database installation. This question seems to be about PHP programming and is unrelated to the phpMyAdmin application. XAMPP has several components and, while phpMyAdmin is included in the bundle, it's not a part of the code you've posted here.

Comment: Any help to solve the issue.